# Inserting elements to vector in c++

Tags: c++, vector

I need to insert for every element of vector it's opposite.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
int main() {
  std::vector < int > vek {1,2,3};
  std::cout << vek[0] << " " << vek[1] << " " << vek[2] << std::endl;
  for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
    std::cout << i << " " << vek[i] << std::endl;
    vek.insert(vek.begin() + i + 1, -vek[i]);
  }
  std::cout << std::endl;
  for (int i: vek) std::cout << i << " ";
  return 0;
}
```

OUTPUT:

```
1 2 3
0 1  // it should be 0 1 (because vek[0]=1)
1 -1 // it should be 1 2 (because vek[1]=2)
2 1  // it should be 2 3 (because vek[2]=3)

1 -1 1 -1 2 3 // it should be 1 -1 2 -2 3 -3
```

Could you explain me why function `insert` doesn't insert the correct value of vector? What is happening here?

Note: Auxiliary vectors (and other data types) are not allowed

Comment: [How to debug small programs?](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/) It does insert exactly what you request. Think what happens within vector when you `insert` new element there, and where (at what index) are now the values that were previously at indices `0`, `1` and `2`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

During the for loop, you are modifying the vector:

After the first iteration which inserts `-1`, the vector becomes `[1, -1, 2, 3]`. Therefore, `vec[1]` becomes `-1` rather than `2`. The index of `2` becomes `2`. And after inserting `-2` into the vector, the index of the original value `3` becomes `4`.

In the for loop condition, you need to add index `i` by 2, instead of 1:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
int main() {
  std::vector < int > vek {1,2,3};
  std::cout << vek[0] << " " << vek[1] << " " << vek[2] << std::endl;
  for (int i = 0; i < 3 * 2; i+=2) {
    std::cout << i << " " << vek[i] << std::endl;
    vek.insert(vek.begin() + i + 1, -vek[i]);
  }
  std::cout << std::endl;
  for (int i: vek) std::cout << i << " ";
  return 0;
}
```